# Delete remove functionality for last row in ng-grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I have functionality that allows my ng-grid to remove rows in which when you click the remove button, the row is deleted from the ng-grid. Below is an example of how I have it set up now:

http://plnkr.co/edit/NL7sMGT6acdUHAAZPNba?p=preview

I want to get it so that the remove button disappears on the very last row. In the example above, for example, all but the `Enos` entry would have no delete button. Also, if I created a new row under `Enos`, I would have it so that Enos would then have a `remove` button and the new row under `Enos` would have no delete functionality. I have the functionality to add/remove rows, but I simply want to get the remove button to disappear on the last row. How would I do so?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22828722/ng-grid-how-to-show-hide-button-in-a-column-cell-for-last-row/22836499#22836499

Comment: Oops, that is nearly the same thing @Steve Greatrex suggested earlier. Sorry.

Comment: Hi @mainguy thanks for your input! I looked at your question answer and I really like how you implemented the "Add Item" implementation at the last row. Is there a way to combine the below answer with your answer? e.g. Have the "Add Item" implementation at the last row which the delete button is hidden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`ng-hide`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) directive to hide the button when the row index is the last one in the collection:

```
<input type="button" 
  value="remove" 
  ng-click="removeRow()" 
  ng-hide="row.rowIndex == $parent.myData.length-1" />
```

This uses the `$parent` property to access the original list on the parent scope to get the count.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you for the help! Just one question then: How can I add a button into the row in which I hid the delete button? I wanted to scrap the implementation for adding rows I have above and I want to just put an "add" button in place of the hidden delete button. Any ideas? Thanks!