# UI-Grid 3.0 how to show/hide button in a column cell for first row

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know it's bad to reference other questions but since I cannot comment on this guys page, the best I can do is post his question here and ask, here is his link:

[ng-grid how to show/hide button in a column cell for last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22828722/ng-grid-how-to-show-hide-button-in-a-column-cell-for-last-row)

Now the question I have is how would I apply this concept but instead only hide the action button on the first row. I have a delete button on all my rows but I cannot hide the delete button on the first row only. I've even tried `ng-hide="row.rowIndex==0"` assuming the index value of zero would hide the delete button but it doesn't.

**UPDATE:**
I have answer below. I figured out that ui grid 3.0 doesn't really have index values but if you apply what I have below into cellTemplate you can render index values for the rows and manipulate the rows to hide/show what you want.

`cellTemplate: '<div ng-hide{{grid.renderContainers.body.visibleRowCache.indexOf(row)}}==0"><a class="sidePadding" title="Delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash text-danger cursorHover"></span></a></div>'`

Comment: Can you include the code that you have tried here?

Comment: I wrote the ng-hide wrong I meant row.rowIndex==0 not row.rowIndex>0

Comment: I just added in my code

Comment: I figured it out ng-hide="{{grid.renderContainers.body.visibleRowCache.indexOf(row)}}==0, it works perfectly now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out ng-hide="{{grid.renderContainers.body.visibleRowCache.indexO‌​f(row)}}==0", it works perfectly now! :)